# Microsoft Power Automate "Follow-up Question" Flow

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

At work I occasionally have to field questions in our teams channel for development support. I often have to ask the same follow up questions every time, so I'm looking into ways to help streamline this process.

I've been researching Power Automate and would like to build a flow that looks like this:

- The flow is triggered when a user posts a new message in the channel
- Reads the text of the message and determines whether they included some data (software version number or a link to a repository, for example)
- Flow bot posts an adaptive card (which tags the user if possible) and prompts them to enter some pieces of info they haven't already provided.

Later on I'd like to add the capability to add this data to a spreadsheet and/or ping the developers on my team to answer the question.

One problem I'm facing early on is that the flow bot posts the adaptive card multiple times as if it's stuck in a trigger-loop.

- How can I prevent this trigger loop?
- What variables should I be trying to extract from the original question?
- How can I use those variables later on in the flow? For example, when trying to create a 'user' variable to tag later, the tag displays as @{variables('user')}.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide us the flow so that we can understand which connector are you using for adaptive card.

Comment: @Sridevi-MSFT thanks for your reply. I've made some progress on this and will post a new, updated question.